# Problem in solving algorithm polynomial regression,least squares method in Octave

Tags: statistics, regression, octave

I am trying to implement polynomial regression using the least squares method. There was a problem while plotting the 3rd graph, it is not displayed.
I think it's about the implementation of the formula y=ax+b.
But in my case, in first I got experimental data values using inline functions `polyfit` and polyval.

```
x=0:0.1:5;
y=3*x+2;
y1=y+randn(size(y));
k=1;#Polynom
X1=0:0.01:10
B=polyfit(x,y1,k);
Y1=polyval(B,X1);
```

And after all, I am already using a linear model to solve the polynomial regression using the method of least squares.

```
Y2=Y1'*x+B'; -----this problem formula
subplot(3,2,3);
plot(x,Y1,'-b',X1,y1,'LineWidth');
title('y1=ax+b'); 
xlabel('x'); 
ylabel('y');
grid on;
```

As a result, no graph is drawn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check size of the vector: x and Y1 are not same length, same for X1 and y1.

You probably want to plot as:

```
plot(x,y1,'-b',X1,Y1,'LineWidth', 1);
```

Comment: Yes,there was and error with vectors size