# The problem with the dimensions of a matrix when computing the least squares method

Tags: regression, octave, octave-gui

My previous topic in this area.

[Problem in solving algorithm polynomial regression,least squares method in Octave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67380853/problem-in-solving-algorithm-polynomial-regression-least-squares-method-in-octav/67394619#67394619)

I decided not to change the main questions, but to create a new question for each problem.

This time, the problem is as follows.I worked with least square method in polynomial regression.

Differentiating this function with respect to the vector of parameters b and equating the derivatives to zero, we obtain the system of equations (in matrix form).This formula.

[image: (X^{T}X)b=X^{T}y.]

That is, if I want to express b from here, I need to do what I did.

```
b=X^{T}y/(X^{T}X)=> b=X'*y1/(X'*X)
```

Code:

```
#Generating random values ​​of experimental data
x=0:0.1:5;
y=3*x+2;
y1=y+randn(size(y));
k=5;#Polynomial degree
X=[x' ones(length(x),1)];
b=X'*y1/(X'*X); Error: operator *: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 2x51, op2 is 1x51)\
```

Yes, the dimensions of the arrays `X` and `y1` do not coincide. Attached screenshots will show everything.In this screenshot variables X,y1 and X'(transposed).

[image]

Then I decided to select 1 column from the array `X` and multiply it by `y1`.

[image]

If you look at the screenshots, you will see that now the transposed `X'` matches the `y1` dimensions. That is, there should be no error, but it still exists.

Comment: Note that `A/B` is not the same as `B\A`. If you start with `(X'*X) * b = X' * y1`, then you left-divide on both sides by `(X'*X)` to solve for `b`: `(X'*X) \ (X'*X) * b = (X'*X) \ X' * y1` -> `b = (X'*X) \ X' * y1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You math is wrong. You can not just randomly divide where you want when doing matrix operations.

The least square solution is

```
b=(X'*X)^-1 * X' * y
```

Also your definition of `y` is wrong, or your sized don't fit.

```
x=0:0.1:5;
y=(3*x+2)'; %transpose!
y1=y+randn(size(y));
X=[x' ones(length(x),1)];
```

The inverse of a matrix is something you should never take numerically. Luckily there is something called the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse, which ensures that when used, you will get the least squares solution to your original problem. So lets use that.

```
b=pinv(X'*X)*X'*y;
b_with_noise=pinv(X'*X)*X'*y1;
```

Note that the following is basically zero to numerical precission, which mean it is correct.

```
sum(X*b-y)

ans =

  -5.8176e-14
```

Now, in MATLAB/octave you can do this much easier as :

```
b=X\y;
b_with_noise=X\y1;
```

MATLAB will find the best algorithm to compute the least squares solution. [`mldivide`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html) has more information (octave docs are a bit more lacking, but should work in the same way).